# SRID in parametric SQL View in Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, wms, layers, wfs

I want to create parametric SQL View, which provide feature collection of my route, which bbox is in depending on entered parameters. I add some SQL Script which is returned some columns, and one of them is geometry column of type LineString with SRID 4326.

When I tried refresh atributes and check *Guess geometry type and srid* geometry was not set up as you can see on screen:

[image]

Type is still Geometry not Linestring, and SRID is -1. So my questions are:

- Should I set this manualy to LineString? And if yes, should I set SRID of my column in database (4326) or that SRID what I need (900913).
- Geoserver layer display this area which is covered in bbox, so if I understad, I have to set bbox of whole area, which is my route could contains? So if my data are whole planet so I need set bbox of whole planet or what ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

GeoServer "guesses" by asking the underlying database, which sometimes cannot provide a good answer, for example:

- PostGIS without a declaration of the subtype and srid in the table
- Oracle in most cases, as the information can be only provided as a constraint while creating the spatial index and very few people enter it

In case they are missing, it's up to you to enter the values (that's why they are editable):

- The right type of geometry
- The srid matching what you actually have in the table

Publishing should normally retain the native CRS, all OGC service can do reprojection on the fly.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I am using PostGIS. So I tried enter linestring of geometry and srid 900913 and when I confirm, and click calculate bbox from SRS nothing be added.

Comment: I believe GeoServer does not have noticed that a native SRS appeared. Try creating the layer from scratch again, giving it a SRID right away.

Comment: I have native SRS that what I enter during SQL View configuration to geometry column. I enter 900913 because I need that, but my data in PostGIS has 4326. Do you think is it OK? And next I click to compute bbox and nothing happened. Herese is screen where you can see I have set native srs https://ctrlv.cz/shots/2017/03/18/fX59.png

I also tried add manualy these values: -20037508.34,-20037508.34,20037508.34,20037508.34 but from this when I tried compute lat/lon give me some wrong values 0,-1,0 and so on

Comment: No, it's not ok, you have to put the actual srid of the geometries.

Comment: Just one question, in geoserver API, how to implement this feature? I mean how to guess the SRID of the SQL View?